# Is there a way to pass parameter for textarea-rows from database to html

Tags: python, web2py

If have a textfield defined as `Field('title', 'text', label = T('Please enter something:'))`. It is rendered as a textarea.

Is it possible to pass some custom-parameters for this field like `rows="5"`in `<textarea rows="5" name="title" .... ></textarea>`

I mean the easy way, without writing a custom widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Field('title', 'text', label=T('Please enter something:'),
      widget=lambda f, v: SQLFORM.widgets.text.widget(f, v, _rows=5))
```

For more details, see [the relevant section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Widgets) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar answer here: [Custom CSS Classes for widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661166/custom-css-classes-for-sqlform-widget-input-in-web2py)

This answer also applies to my question: instead if passing `['_class] = "bla"` just pass `['_rows'] = "x"`